# Pandas does not fill nan values with empty string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the Nan values with empty strings. This is the code I have

```
df.replace({r'[^\x00-\x7F]+': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
col_buyername = basicinfo.get('buyer_name')
col_product = basicinfo.get('product_name')
col_quantity = basicinfo.get('quantity')
col_price = basicinfo.get('price')
print(df[col_buyername])

df.loc[:, [col_buyername, col_product]].fillna("", inplace=True)

print('after')
print(df[col_buyername])
```

the output is

```
0          NaN
1          Roy Thomas
2          NaN
3          NaN

Name: buyer name, dtype: object

after

0          NaN
1          Roy Thomas
2          NaN
3          NaN

Name: buyer name, dtype: object
```

Why is the fillna nothing setting it to be blank strings?

Comment: ``NaN`` means ``Not a Number``. it is ``float``, not ``str``. You can't put string to a float

Comment: it is showing as dtype:object?? how can I put blank str there ?

Comment: @Karina when i did ```df.fillna('', inplace=True)``` it was working

Comment: oh I think this is your mistake: ``df = `` ``df[[col_buyername, col_product, col_address]].fillna("", inplace=True)``. Add ``df = `` and problem is solved (probably)

Comment: @MichaelO. will this work ```df[df[[col_buyername, col_product, col_address]].isna()] = ""``` I got error ```TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value```

Comment: That will drop all other columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing with square brackets and a list of columns creates a copy, so you modify a temporary object, not the original dataframe.

You have three possible solutions, either pass a dict of column -> replacement for each column, assign or loop over the columns.

#### Looping

```
for col in (col_buyername, col_product):
    df[col].fillna('', inplace=True)
```

#### Assignment

```
df[[col_buyername, col_product]] = df[[col_buyername, col_product]].fillna('')
```

#### dict

```
df.fillna({col_buyername: '', col_product: ''}, inplace=True)
```

The loop and the dict approach should be a little more efficient than the reassignment.

For more info on when pandas created copies and when not,  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/3838691

Comment: This still has not fixed my issue.

Comment: Added my question with latest code

Comment: Sorry, yes, even with the loc, it does not work (surprised me). I updated my answer.